# Return value when using function pointer (also using OpenMP)

Tags: c

When I change quick short function code for example output always at 0, Program go in case0 change the quicksortarr 'values become 0 this is okey but when other case ("case1") start shellSortarr is changed also quicksortarr is changed and become same as (shellsortarr) therefore I won't compare this array. 
I think my mistake pointers.

My second question(less important) is I want to omp functions for using %100 CPU I found this codes but I guess, This is only work before for loop

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)

omp_get_wtime();
```

Do you have suggesiton

```
 double sort(int *(*func)(int*, int), int *a, int len,int i) {
        time_t end, begin;
        int *b = malloc(len * sizeof *b);
        if (!b) { perror("sort: malloc"); return 0; }
        memcpy(b, a, len * sizeof b[0]);    

//for example b = 10,3,15,6,123

        int *selectionSortarr;
        int *quicksortarr;

        switch( k%2 ) {
        case 0:
        begin = clock();

//b = 10,3,15,6,123 

        quicksortarr = func(b, len);
//for example func(quicksort) is wrong and quicksortarr become 0,0,0,0,0
        end = clock();  
        k++;
        break;
        case 1:     
        begin = clock();
//b is again b = 10,3,15,6,123  
        shellSortarr = func(b, len);
// after that shellsortarr and quicksortarr become 3,6,10,15,123
//therefore compare function is print "File's sorted arrays are equal"
        end = clock();      
        compare(quicksortarr,shellSortarr,len,i);
        k=0;    
        break;  
        }   
        free(b);
        return (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    }
```

.I call function like this:

```
while (fscanf(f, "%d", &input) == 1) a[len++] = input;
    quick[i] = sort(quickSort,     a, len,i);
    shell[i] = sort(shellSort,     a, len,i);
```

.My sorting functions like this:

```
int *shellSort(int x3[], int n){

    //sorting code
    return x3;
}
```

.My compare functions like this:

```
void compare(int *arr1,int *arr2,int len,int y) {
    int i=0;
    int check=0;
        for (i=0; i<len; i++){
        if (arr1[i] != arr2[i])     
                check++;
                break;

    }
    if (check !=0) printf("%i . File's sorted arrays are not equal difference start at %i . variable in array\n",y,i);
    else printf("%i. File's sorted arrays are equal\n",y);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need extra space for quicksortarr and shellSortarr

```
double sort(void (*func)(int*, int), int *a, int len,int i) {
    time_t end, begin;
    int *b = malloc(len * sizeof *b);
    if (!b) { perror("sort: malloc"); return 0; }
    memcpy(b, a, len * sizeof b[0]);    
    switch( k%2 ) {
    case 0:
    begin = clock();    
    func(b, len);
    end = clock();  
    int *quicksortarr = malloc(len * sizeof *quicksortarr);
    if (!quicksortarr) { perror("sort: malloc"); return 0; }
    memcpy(quicksortarr, b, len * sizeof quicksortarr[0]);
    k++;
    break;
    case 1:     
    begin = clock();
    func(b, len);
    int *shellSortarr = malloc(len * sizeof *shellSortarr);
    if (!shellSortarr) { perror("sort: malloc"); return 0; }
    memcpy(shellSortarr, b, len * sizeof shellSortarr[0]);
    end = clock();
    k++;
    break;

    compare(quicksortarr,shellSortarr,len,i);
    k=0;    
    break;  
    }   

    free(b);
    return (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}
```

you don't need return anymore so;

```
 void shellSort(int x3[], int n){

    //sorting code
       }
```

Also `#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)` uses only for loop if your sorting code use for you can add with `<omp.h>` library